# scheduling a print command at specific timings after the script started in Python

Tags: python, timing, benchmarking

I want to schedule a text 'hello world' at various timings (form a list), since the script has started. What would be the best way to do it?

This is probably wrong, but what I have so far:

```
import time
times = [1.76493425, 3.10174059, 4.49576803, 10.99379224, 18.84178369] #at these times since onset of script, a text "hello world" should be printed

start = time.time()

def main():
    for cuetime in times:
        print ('hello world', ' - timing: ', cuetime, ' - now: ', time.time()- start)
    yield viztask.waitTime(cuetime)

main()
```

This gives me:

```
('hello world', ' - timing: ', 1.76493425, ' - now: ', 0.0)
('hello world', ' - timing: ', 3.10174059, ' - now: ', 1.7699999809265137)
('hello world', ' - timing: ', 4.49576803, ' - now: ', 3.5379998683929443)
('hello world', ' - timing: ', 10.99379224, ' - now: ', 5.305999994277954)
('hello world', ' - timing: ', 18.84178369, ' - now: ', 7.075000047683716)
```

But what I actually need is the timing elements/items to be the same as the "now" time, because the elements in the timing list ARE the timings at which the text "hello world" should be printed relative to the onset of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [`schedule`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) module. Haven't worked with it before, but you can achieve your goal quite easily:

```
import schedule
import time
from functools import partial
# your specified list of times
times = [1.76493425, 3.10174059, 4.49576803, 10.99379224, 18.84178369]
# define a job you want to do
def job(t, start):
    print ('hello world', ' - timing: ', t, ' - now: ', time.time()- start)
    # pop the job right away from schedule.jobs, so it runs only once
    return schedule.CancelJob
# get the starting time
start = time.time()
# for each time add what to do
for t in times:
    # using partial so i can pass arguments to job
    schedule.every(t).seconds.do(partial(job, t, start))
# and run it inside a lop
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    # schedule.jobs is just a list of jobs
    if not schedule.jobs:
        break
```

Prints out:

```
hello world  - timing:  1.76493425  - now:  1.7650279998779297
hello world  - timing:  3.10174059  - now:  3.101846933364868
hello world  - timing:  4.49576803  - now:  4.495898962020874
hello world  - timing:  10.99379224  - now:  10.993950605392456
hello world  - timing:  18.84178369  - now:  18.84195566177368
```

Comment: Thanks quapka, this is excellent, especially the comments, which make it transparent.

Comment: I am glad it helped. There is room to improve it. Probably passing `start` each time. For some reason I think of decorators and context managers. But those would be interesting if the jobs were more complicated I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) library for more details. Here is a code sample which is not 100% accurate but should do the trick if you are not in the need of a millisec precision.

```
import time
import sched

def print_time(cuetime):
    global start
    print ('hello world', ' - timing: ', cuetime, ' - now: ', time.time()- start)

start = time.time()
times = [1.76493425, 3.10174059, 4.49576803, 10.99379224, 18.84178369] 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    for cuetime in times:
        s.enter(cuetime, 1, print_time, (cuetime,))
    s.run()
```

Comment: thanks Luc, the scheduler was definetely the way to go